# How to fix 'stop.at is not a function' error?

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-animate, svg.js

With v2.5 it's ok, but v3 say "stop.at is not a function" when I try define the gradient.

```
<svg id="svg1"> </svg>

var draw = SVG('#svg1').size(100,100);
var linear = draw.gradient('linear', function(stop) {
  stop.at(0, '#f06', 1);
  stop.at(1, '#0f9', 1);
});

draw.rect(100, 100).fill( linear );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var linear = draw.gradient('linear', function(add) {
  add.stop(0, '#f06', 1);
  add.stop(1, '#0f9', 1);
});
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow, perhaps  you could include why OP made a mistake and what this does to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Because the documentation is not up to date. That's why.